# Apply Laravel filter using regex as route name

Tags: regex, laravel, routes

I'm trying to apply a route filter to all the routes **except homepage**. I do it like this:

```
Route::whenRegex('/^\/[\S]+/', 'myFilter');
```

So, basically, I'm saying: match all the routes starting with `/`, followed by any non-whitespace character(s). However, the filter doesn't work.

The filter itself:

```
Route::filter('myFilter', function() {
    if (Session::has('userRegState')) {
        return Redirect::action('DefaultController@home');
    }
});
```

I checked it - the `userRegState` session variable is set, but no redirect is done. Is the regex used in the filter wrong?

Comment: use a different delimiter.

Comment: I tried `#...#` and `%...%` already. No success.

Comment: @lesssugar What is the purpose of this route? How often will the user enter space characters in the URL?

Comment: It's not about the space. The point is to apply the route when it's valid, so `/page1` or `/page2`, not when someone puts `/ page3` in the bar. If the session variable is set, I need to force certain action from my user, hence the filter.

Comment: @lesssugar Isn't you application built in such a way that the user navigates it with links? I.e. what is the chance that the user enters a space character in the address bar? And then let it redirect to 404?

Comment: Just a small remark: you don't need square brackets around `\S` since it's a one character.

Comment: @silkfire I don't think you understand. If my `userRegState` is set in the session, I need to redirect the user to homepage (and perform other actions there). The non-whitespace check is only there to prevent running the filter for strings that are wrong URLs... The check doesn't really matter. The point is the regex does not work ;)

Comment: @lesssugar True but let's say you want to redirect on all pages that start with `page` then I'd just use: `Route::get('/page{number}', ...);`

Answer (score 0):

OK, it seems there might be some kind of forward slash stripping done in the routing logic of Laravel, which makes my pattern not match what it should. To fix it, I omit the forward slash.

Instead of this:

```
Route::whenRegex('/^\/[\S]+/', 'myFilter');
```

I do that:

```
Route::whenRegex('/^\S{2}/', 'myFilter');
```

The final regex matches anything that starts with at least 2 non-whitespace characters. In my case it's forward slash followed by any non-whitespace character, like `/a`, `/page2`, etc.